# Which type of external drives are good for SQL backup files?

Tags: sql-server

As a part of database maintenance we are thinking of taking daily backups onto an external/firewire drives. Are there any specific recommended drives for the frequent read/write operations from sql server 2000 to take backups?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, just don't use USB 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact is that harddrives over a period of time will fail. The best two solutions
I can recommend unfortunately do not avail of using harddrives.

Using a tape backup, granted is slower but you get the flexibility of having the option of offsite backups. It is easy to put a tape in the boot of a car. Rotating the tapes means that you can have pretty recent protection against any unforseen situations.

Another option is an online backup solution where the backups are encrypted and copied offsite. My reccommendation is definitly at least having some sort of offsite backup external to the building that you keep the SQL servers. After all it is "disaster" recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any external drive can be used here, provided it has the space to hold your backups and enough performance to get the backups there.  The specifics depend on your exact requirements.

In my experience, FireWire tends to outperform USB for disk activity, regardless of their theoretical maximum transfer rates.  And FireWire 800 will perform even better yet.  I have found poor performance from FireWire and USB drives when you have multiple concurrent reads/writes going on, but with backups, it's generally more large sequential reads and writes.

Another option that is a little bit more complex to setup and manage, but can provide you with greater flexibility and performance is external SATA (eSATA).  You can even get Hot Swappable external SATA enclosures for even greater convenience, and ease of taking your backups offsite.

However, another related option that I've had excellent success with is to setup a separate server to act as your backup server.  You can use whatever disk options you choose (FireWire, SATA, eSATA, SCSI, FiberChannel, iSCSI, etc), and share out that disk storage as a network share (I use NFS and Samba on a Linux box, but for a Windows oriented network, a Windows share will work fine).  You can then access the shares across the network and backup multiple machines to it.  Also, the separation of backup server from your production machines will give you greater flexibility if you need to take it offline for maintenance, adding/removing storage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Drobo!

A USB hard drive RAID array that uses normal - off the shelf hard drives.  4 bays, when you need more space, buy another hard drive.  Out of bays?  Buy bigger hard drives and replace your smallest in the array.

http://www.drobo.com/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the databases speed of the drive can be a real factor. I would look into something like Drobo but with an eSata or SAS interface. There is nothing more entertaining than watching a terabyte go through USB 2.0. Also, you might consider something like hyperbac or RedGate SQL Backup to compress the backup and make it easier to fit on the drive as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, external drives aren't a good option - unless your database is really small.

Other than some of the options others have listed, you can also use UNC/Network shares as a great 'off-box' option.

Check out the following video for some other options:
[SQL Server Backup Options (Free Video)](http://www.sqlservervideos.com/sqlserver-backups/backup-options)

And the videos on configuring backups on the site will show you how to specify a network path for backup purposes.